# Is it possible to return an HttpResponse object in render function?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Reasons for why someone would want to do this aside, is it possible? Something along the lines of

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from data_viewer.models.data_view import DataPlugin
from django.http import HttpResponse

    class CMSPlugin(CMSPluginBase):

        def render(self, context, instance)
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
            return response
```

Usually render functions require a context to be returned, thus this code doesn't work as is. Once again, I know this isn't typical. I just want to know if it's possible

Thanks in advance, all help is appreciated!

Comment: Just FYI this can be confusing since *the render function* would normally refer to django's ubiquitous render shortcut, not a django-CMS method. My suggestion for questions extremely specific to a package is to dig into the cms source to see how you can accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

The `render` method is very unfortunately named and should really be called `get_context`. It **must** return a dictionary or `Context` instance, see the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#the-simplest-plugin)

If you want to extend django CMS with something that returns `HttpResponse` objects, have a look at [apphooks](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html#integration-apphooks).